# Writing errors and output to a text file and Console

Tags: powershell, redirect

I am trying to write the entire output (errors included) of an executing script to the console and a file at the same time. I have tried several different options:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 | tee -filePath C:\results.txt # only the output to the file
.\MyScript.ps1 2> C:\results.txt # only the errors to the file and not the console
.\MyScript.ps1 > C:\results.txt # only the output to the file and not the console
```

My hope was that I could use the file to review the output/errors.

EDIT:

This is my current test script. The desired results is that all three messages can be seen.

```
function Test-Error 
{
    echo "echo"
    Write-Warning "warning"
    Write-Error "error"       
}

Test-Error 2>&1 | tee -filePath c:\results.txt
```

Comment: @JasonMArcher thanks for updating the tags on this question! Is there anything extra we should do since it is fixed in V3 and I was originally using V2? Thanks.

Comment: That depends, do you only want answers to V2?  This isn't a problem that is specific to V2.  Thus the best idea is to preference actual answers with the version of PowerShell they are intended for.  :)

Comment: I added some notes to the existing answers about PS version compatibility.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 .\MyScript.ps1 2>&1 | tee -filePath c:\results.txt
```

`2>&1` is what you're looking for

*Note: This answer works great in PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0, but will capture ONLY standard output and errors in PowerShell 3.0 and later.*

Comment: This is very close. I added the script I am using to test my desired functionality to the question. It is able to get the standard output and errors but not warnings. Any other ideas?

Comment: You don't have a lot of good options for that.  Read the cmdlet help topics for WRite-Warning and Write-Error and you'll see they're fundamentally different.  Write-Warning writes to the host, Write-Error writes to the error output stream.  You can redirect streams, but writing to the host goes to the host.  Your only alternative is the WarningVariable, etc. common parameters.  You should be able to make all warning/error/output data redirect to a variable using this.  See the about_CommonParameters help topic for more info.

Comment: BTW, looks like you're not the first to run into this.  I guy I used to work with has a good description of the problem here: http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6926.entry

Comment: The solution Kieth used should work for us as a temporary solution. It seems like I need to rethink how we log within our cmdlets. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you end up deciding to use for a longer term solution? I'm investigating tee vs transcripts. Tee is simpler and cleaner... if only it captured all the output we wanted.

Comment: As of PowerShell 3, you can do: `.\MyScript.ps1 *>&1 | tee -filePath c:\results.txt`, that means redirect all output streams, as warning, debug and verbose exist. See [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

I wasn't satisfied with any answer I was finding, so I mixed a few and came up with this (in **PowerShell 3.0+**):

```
$output = try{your_command *>&1}catch{$_}
```

With this you can capture all errors and output that are generated by trying to use `your_command`.

It catches exceptions when you use a non-existent command:

```
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> $output = try{your_command *>&1}catch{$_}
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> echo $output
your_command : The term 'your_command' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ $output = try{your_command 2>&1}catch{$_}
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (your_command:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\jdgregson>
```

It catches exceptions when you pass invalid arguments to an existing command:

```
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> $output = try{cat C:\invalid-path.txt *>&1}catch{$_}
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> echo $output
cat : Cannot find path 'C:\invalid-path.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:15
+ $output = try{cat C:\invalid-path.txt 2>&1}catch{$_}
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\invalid-path.txt:String) [Ge
   t-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCo
   ntentCommand
```

And it catches the output if there was no problem with your command at all:

```
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> $output = try{cat C:\valid-path.txt *>&1}catch{$_}
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> echo $output
this file is really here
```

It works for your example too:

```
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> $output = try{Test-Error *>&1}catch{$_}
PS C:\Users\jdgregson> echo $output
echo
WARNING: warning
Test-Error : error
At line:1 char:15
+ $output = try{Test-Error *>&1}catch{$_}
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
   n,Test-Error
```

Answer (score 7):

By default only the Success stream of data is passed on to the Output file. To direct errors and warnings you will have to add something like this :

> your script 3>&1 2>&1 | Out-file log.txt

[image: Powershell redirection operators.]

Comment: Perfect. You can find documentation of Powershell redirection parameters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get both errors and results in the same file. A workaround that worked for me:

`.\MyScript.ps1 2> C:\errors.txt | tee -filePath C:\results.txt`

Update:
I have worked further and I used `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` in my mode to capture everything and it worked!

Comment: The other answer correctly writes stderr and stdout to the file. The original problem was not being able to also include warnings. `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` are very useful and still worth learning about.