# Powershell EMail: Script for sending eMails not working on my windows

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am not from Powershell background.

I am about to schedule task in which a mail is required to send; if disk size is less then expected limit.

Following is script which i am using:

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt";

foreach($server in $servers)
{
 # Get fixed drive info
  $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
  foreach($disk in $disks)
  {
      $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
      [float]$size = $disk.Size;
      [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;

     #Here you have to mention the drive id for example i mentioned 'C' drive below
     if($deviceID -eq "C:")
     {
       $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2);
       $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2);
       $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2);

       if($freeSpaceGB -lt 100)
       {
          $EmailFrom = "monitoring@mydomainname.no"
          $EmailTo = "fatherazrael@evry.com"
          $Subject = "Disk Space"
          $Body = "$disk drive space is less free space in $server server: $freeSpaceGB"
          $SMTPServer = "scan.opinkerfi.is"
          $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
          #$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<From mail ID>", "Password"); //Not Required
          $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)   
       }
    }
 }
}
```

I do not know how to apply logging. Could any one figure out where the problem is? No Logs are there in Event viewer or anywhere.

I am able to configure all this using Event Viewer, Task Scheduler and Performance Tools but i am told to use Powershell.

Comment: If you run the scripte directly from powershell you should be getting error messages (if they exist)

Comment: How to get error output into a log file is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008545/powershell-writing-errors-and-ouput-to-a-text-file-and-console

Comment: If you want a PowerShell script to log something to the eventlog you need to [instruct it to actually do that](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/20/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs.aspx).

Comment: Note: Your script is working perfectly for me.

Comment: I am using it in Task Scheduler. My Disk are 227 GB C: drive and 227 GB D Drive.  I am using Computer Name something.domainname.com as in server list. I am configuring it in task scheduler under actions start a program and give path of .ps1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working for me. Could it be that your disks are above 100GB space?

**if($freeSpaceGB -lt 100)**

You could use some error handling. Try to change email sending part to this:

```
if($freeSpaceGB -lt 1000)
       {
        try {
              $EmailFrom = "monitoring@mydomainname.no"
              $EmailTo = "fatherazrael@evry.com"
              $Subject = "Disk Space"
              $Body = "$disk drive space is less free space in $server server: $freeSpaceGB"
              $SMTPServer = "scan.opinkerfi.is"
              $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
              #$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<From mail ID>", "Password"); //Not Required
              $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
            }
        catch
            {
                $Error[0].Exception.Message | Out-File ($server + '_error.txt')
            }
```

You will get related errors during email send part to current directory with txt files.

Comment: I am using it in Task Scheduler. My Disk are 227 GB C: drive and 227 GB D Drive

Comment: I am using Computer Name something.domainname.com as in server list

Comment: What's amount of free space do you have? because you script currently works only if under 100GB space left. If theres above 100GB it will not send any email. You could try change to if($freeSpaceGB -lt 1000).