# Powershell Out-FIle issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy files with sources on a csv file. I also want to write the console output to a csv to review any missing files during the operation. While the script works fine and copies the file to the destination, the out-file part is not working. It creates the csv file but there's no content. Please help

```
$csvFilePath = "\\someNetworkFOlder\FilePath.csv"
$exportPath =  "\\someNetworkFlder\exportedFiles\"
$logLocation = "\\someNetworkFlder\exportedFiles\Copy_result.csv"

Import-Csv $csvFilePath | ForEach-Object{Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Path |
    Copy-Item -Destination $exportPath -recurse -Force -Verbose} | Out-File -FilePath $logLocation -Append
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008545/writing-errors-and-output-to-a-text-file-and-console which explains why that happens and how to fix it.